# PDO Transaction Update Error on a row using the value of another row from a different table

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

**Updated with current attempt code**

Hi_I’m trying to do a PDO check for a row value, and then an Update statement on a row in a table, using a value from a row from a different table from my database, inside a Transaction, but I keep getting an error.

I have two tables, they are `table1` and `bank`.

`table1` contains the columns `userid` and `ticketamount`.

`bank` contains the columns `userid` and `goldbalance`.

`ticketamount` and `goldbalance` are INTs.
These two rows are never `NULL`, when a user account is created, a value of `0` gets entered into these rows, so there will always be a value in them.

`userid` is a unique column.

What I want to do, is run a PDO transaction which will Update `ticketamount` by adding on whatever value is stored in `goldbalance`, I’m trying to do this by setting it as `ticketamount + (some code to fetch the goldbalance amount here)`.

This is my code in full:

```
<?php
$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


// first, find out if bank.goldbalance is > 0, if it is, then run Update statements and echo "1", else echo "0":

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 'goldbalance' FROM 'bank' WHERE 'userid' = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $userid);
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $stmt->execute();

 if (($result['goldbalance']) > 0){

// if bank.goldbalance is greater than 0, then run this transaction:
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // prepare UPDATE statement
    $sql = 'UPDATE table1 t
     LEFT JOIN bank b
     ON b.userid = t.userid
     SET t.ticketamount = t.ticketamount + b.goldbalance
     WHERE t.userid = :id';

    echo "SQL=" . $sql ;

    // prepare statement and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $userid);
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $stmt->execute();

    // 2nd statement...
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE 'bank' SET 'goldbalance' = 0 WHERE 'userid' = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $userid);
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $stmt->execute();

    $conn->commit();

    // echo "1" to verify transaction completed
    echo "1";

} else {
    echo '0';
}
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $conn = null;
    ?>
```

If bank.goldbalance = 0 then there's no point in running the transaction, so I want to check that first, if it does = 0 then I just want to echo "0", but if it = >0 then I want to run the transaction and echo "1" when it completes.

I'm trying to make the transaction take the value that's in bank.goldbalance and then add it on to the value that's in table1.ticketamount. Then, the second part of the transaction should set bank.goldbalance to be "0".

The response I’m getting in the console right now with the above code is this:

> "Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''bank' WHERE 'userid' = '113234523347'' at line 1"

I can't see what's wrong with this particular piece of code.

Any additional advice on this problem would be really great,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're using the wrong identifier qualifiers for your table(s)/column(s) . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: Here, add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, and you'll see "more" syntax errors.

Comment: Don't use single quotes around identifiers, use **backticks**. (Single quotes are used around string literals, not around table names or column names.) Also, I don't see any linkage between the `$stmt->execute()` and `$result`... but you don't need to run a separate statement to check `goldbalance`, It would be faster to just run the UPDATE when goldbalance is zero, MySQL will figure out that row doesn't actually need to be changed. (If we're expecting goldbalance to be zero almost always, then I'd do the separate check, that is, when running the UPDATE is the exception, rather than the rule.)

Comment: You can remove the `LEFT` keyword from the UPDATE statement, if you know you're always going to have a matching row from `bank`. With the LEFT keyword in there, if a matching row isn't found in bank, then the statement will adding NULL, which will result in a NULL value, and I suspect you don't want to overwrite the value of ticketamount with a NULL. (If you leave the LEFT keyword in, you need to wrap goldbalance in an IFNULL function to get a zero in place of the NULL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging this, break this into *two* steps.  First, generate the text of the SQL statement as a string into variable.

Then, pass the variable to the `prepare`.

Between those two, you can do an `echo` or `var_dump` of the string variable.

---

In your case, this is a simple PHP string literal/concatenation issue.

That second double quote ends the string literal, and the following `SELECT ...` isn't recognized by PHP.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE 'table1' 
        SET 'ticketamount' = 'ticketamount'+("SELECT 'goldbalance'
                                             ^
```

There's issues with the single quotes; with MySQL, those should be backticks around the identifiers

---

Since you're not including any variables in the string, it's a static literal (which is a very good thing, in terms of SQL), you can use single quotes rather than double quotes:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `table1` t
           SET t.`ticketamount` = t.`ticketamount` 
                                + ( SELECT b.`goldbalance`
                                      FROM `bank` b
                                     WHERE b.`userid` = :id1
                                     LIMIT 1
                                  )
          WHERE t.`userid` = :id2';
#echo "SQL=" . $sql ;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Note that there are problems using the same bind variable name more than once in a statement with PDO (at least, there used to be) because of the way PDO is actually converting that to a positional notation from the named notation.

I also added a `LIMIT 1` clause to the subquery, because MySQL will throw an error if we return more than one row. (If `userid` is unique in the `bank` table, it won't make a difference.  If it's not unique, which row do we want? the newest, the one with the greatest value for goldbalance, etc. We can add an aggregate or an ORDER BY to make it more deterministic.)

There's also an issue if a row isn't returned, we're going to get a NULL value, and when we add a NULL we get a NULL as a result. Do we want to handle a missing row or a NULL value as a zero?

If `userid` is unique in the `bank` table, I'd do this query with join operation. To emulate the subquery, we'd need an outer join, e.g.

And since none of the identifiers are reserved words, we don't need backticks around the identifiers.

```
  UPDATE table1 t
    LEFT
    JOIN bank b
      ON b.userid = t.userid
     SET t.ticketamount = t.ticketmamount + IFNULL(b.goldbalance,0)
   WHERE t.userid = :id
```

If we want to emulate the original query, we'd need to remove the `IFNULL` wrapper from around `b.goldbalance` so it could return a NULL, so ticketamount would be set to NULL.

If we don't want to update the row if the related row is "missing" from bank, we could do an inner join instead of an outer join (i.e. remove the `LEFT` keyword.)

---

Comment: Hi @spencer7593 thanks very much for your reply! After reading your answer I realised that I don't need to run the transaction if goldbalance = 0, so I've added an if/else check for this at the start of the script. I've been trying to implement your code, but I keep getting a strange error in the console, I've updated my entire question and added some info about the rows, I'd be really grateful if you could take a look, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Emily, don't use single quotes around identifiers, use **backticks**. I think the single quotes around table and column names are a problem in this SQL statement (in your code): `"UPDATE 'bank' SET 'goldbalance' = 0 WHERE 'userid' = :id"`. Also, you can remove the `LEFT`  keyword from the example statement I showed, if you only update `table1` when there's a matching row in `bank`. It would be faster just to run the `UPDATE` even when goldbalance is 0, there's no need to run a separate statement to check that first. (I'd only do a separate check of goldbalance if it's almost always zero.)